# Finder "copy as pathname" adding smb:// on Mojave

Tags: finder, mojave, smb

On previous MacOS versions using the "copy as pathname" option from Finder would provide me the local mounted path on SMB resources

ex:
/Volumes/mountname/folder1/folder2

Now on Mojave its giving me an smb:// url to the same mounted SMB resouces

ex:
smb://server/mountname/folder1/folder2

Is there any way to change the format back to the pre-Mojave version?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed as of 10.14.5