# For 10.14.6 what does "Improves file-sharing reliability over SMB" mean, specifically?

Tags: macos, mojave, smb, file-sharing

> **Note**
>
> When answering please add references/links for any claims made. Answers based on guesses or assumptions will be deleted.

macOS 10.14.6 was just released.  One of the lines is "Improves file-sharing reliability over SMB".  What specifically has changed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Apple does not provide this level of detail. This applies to Security Updates and other software updates as well.

Comment: (Slighly) related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/349204/finder-copy-as-pathname-adding-smb-on-mojave

Comment: @IconDaemon I understand we want to close some questions, but is there harm asking if someone has reverse engineered the protocol or if someone knows the last version of open source?  Apple is starting to change SMB in specific and documentation in general. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208209 and even more detail when we engage them in professional services. At some point, if I get a breakthrough I’ll write up what we’re learning between Apple and Nasuni for SMB sharing and best tips for admins.

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not normally provide the level of detail you seek. It doesn't even provide that level to developers and beta-testers in the pre-release seeds for testing purposes.

It may eventually be deduced by sufficient people who used to have a particular problem in that area all reporting some improvement. It may also be uncovered by researchers delving into system files and uncovering relevant strings or other data.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, any answer is necessarily a guess, but for the benefit of others wondering what this update may be referring to, here is my educated guess.

The 10.14.5 version of `smbd` would frequently hang, causing file sharing clients to hang as well.  The workaround was to disable SIP and revert `/usr/sbin/smbd` to the 10.14.4 version.  I am guessing/hoping that this update fixes the problem.

**Update:**

So far, the client hangs I experienced with the 10.14.5 version of `smbd` have not occurred with 10.14.6, so it does appear that the update has fixed that problem.

Comment: Thank you. I found the "improves" misleading as for us it was completely broken. Thank you for sharing your experience @Seth. We went back to old Mac mini with 10.14.0 but will try the 10.14.6 on new Mac mini before sending it back and finding a OS that actually shares. Again thanks Seth I am updating as we speak.

Comment: FWIW, the SMB performance seems better under 10.14.6 than it was under 10.14.4 and earlier.  Volumes are more responsive and spotlight searching within a mounted folder actually works, which I don't recall ever seeing before.